# Looking for suggestions on how to reuse AlertDialogs to confirm actions of contextual menus on the items of an ActivityList

Tags: android

I use a `ListActivity` to display a list of items. The user can long-press an item in the list to display a contextual menu. This menu contains among other things an option to delete the long-pressed item. When the user selects this option, a dialog pops up asking for confirmation of the deletion. Upon confirmation, the item is deleted from the list.

I would like to reuse the `AlertDialog` as much as possible. My attempts at using `onPrepareDialog(int, View, Bundle)` have been defeated by the fact that the `Bundle` is not passed to the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. I end up having to recreate a listener on every invocation.

I see several ways to solve this:

1. recreate the dialog on every occasion (pros: simple, cons: wasteful)
2. keep the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` in a field on the `ListActivity` and keep the item to be deleted as a field of the listener. (pros: no memory waste, cons: need to manage state). Q: is this safe?
3. have `onPrepareDialog` update the title, and bind new `View.OnClickListener`s on the buttons of the `AlertDialog`. (pros: limit waste, cons: new `View.OnClickListener` on every invocation).

If `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` accepted a `Bundle`, I wouldn't have to jump through hoops to keep track of the item being deleted.

This is not a blocker, but I would love to see an elegant solution. I would love to hear your suggestions :)

Here is the code for option #1, if you want to play with this:

```
public class Example extends ListActivity {
  private static final int CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG = 1;
  private static final String POSITION_KEY = "position";

  private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        new String[] { "one", "two" });
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_lovely_menu, menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete_item:
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putInt(POSITION_KEY, info.position);
      showDialog(CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG, bundle);
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
    case CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG:
      final int position = args.getInt(POSITION_KEY);
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
      builder.setCancelable(false);
      builder.setTitle(String.format(
          getString(R.string.confirm_delete), mAdapter.getItem(position)));
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          switch (which) {
          case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
            // Dismiss the dialog to ensure OnDismissListeners are notified.
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
          case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            // Cancel the dialog to ensure OnCancelListeners are notified.
            dialog.cancel();
            break;
          }
          // Remove the dialog so it is re-created next time it is required.
          removeDialog(CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG);
        }
      };
      builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, listener);
      builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, listener);
      return builder.create();
    default:
      return super.onCreateDialog(id, args);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to ask why you consider creating a new dialog each time a user long-presses an item wasteful.  Generally, a dialog is something the user is forced to interact with until an outcome is satisfied at which point the dialog is destroyed and cleaned out of memory.  So, only 1 ever exists at any given time.  What are you wasting in this case?

Comment: Because memory is precious on handheld devices, and speed matters! Dialogs are meant to be reused, that is the purpose of onPrepareDialog. Creating a new dialog each time allocates a pile of objects instead of reusing most of them. These objects will later have to be garbage collected. I am trying to minimize the work required for these dialogs. As I said, this isn't a blocker, but I'd like to find an more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think option 1, or something very close to it, is likely to be the most elegant solution available.

Option 1 and the sample code should work, but the pattern is susceptible to being inadvertently used with the dialog changed to `setCancelable(true)`. If that happens then it is possible to dismiss the dialog by using the Back button and therefore skip the `removeDialog(CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG)`. That would cause the dialog to open next time with potentially the wrong value for position.

For that reason, I think the option 1 approach should be adjusted to relocate the `removeDialog(CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG)` from the `DialogInterface.onClickListener` of `onCreateDialog` to a `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`, set up in `onPrepareDialog`:

```
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
    case CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG:
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                removeDialog(CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG);
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog, args);
    }
}
```

An alternative, avoiding the use of `onPrepareDialog`, is to bind the `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` in `onCreateDialog`:

```
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            removeDialog(CONFIRM_DELETE_DIALOG);
        }
    });
    return dialog;
```